# Numbering theorems from 1 in each section

Tags: numbering, theorems

Is it possible to number every theorem from 1 in each section?

For example, I would like to have the first theorem in the *n*th section simply called Theorem 1 for every *n*.

Comment: You should provide more information, but for a basic setup see my (possible) answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks so much, that is close. I think I have no more information to provide with :) Thanks to your answer, what I want is to make Theorem 1.1 and Theorem 2.1 both as simply Theorem 1.

Comment: I've updated my solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `newtheorem` command has an optional third argument, which is designed for specification of the counter which `drives` the resetting of the theorem counter, in this case `section`, since the request is to start over the theorem number with `1` in a new section.

In order to suppress the leading `1.` etc. from the theorem label, the easiest way is the redefine `\thetheorem` command which is responsible for printing the theorem label number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}{Theory on Brontosaurs, by Miss Ann Elk}

Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{First of second}
Blabla
\end{theorem}

\section{Second Section}


\begin{theorem}{First in 2nd section}
Blabla
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}{First of second}
Blabla
\end{theorem}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. If it is possible to apply your answer to environments such as Exercise or something alike? How to set it up once and for all?

Comment: I think, this is possible, but it's a new question, in my point of view. I'll try

Comment: I tried this    \newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]
\renewcommand{theexer}{\arabic{exercise}}  but it did not work

Comment: Much appreciated; I am looking forward to that. :)

Comment: @Chou: See my answer to your other question

Comment: @Chou You have to write `\renewcommand{\theexer}{\arabic{exer}}`

Comment: @karlkoeller: Oops, did not see the comment by the OP ... thanks for answering it